# Como posso mudar somente uma propriedade de um objeto usando o hook useState

Tags: javascript, react, react-hooks

Eu gostaria de saber como posso alterar somente uma propriedade especifica de um objeto usando o hook useState

```
const [value, setValue] = useState({value1: "abc", value2: "abcd"})
```

Como seria possível alterar somente o **value1** permanecendo os estado do **value2**?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o spread operator na hora de atualizar o valor no State. Ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
setValue(prevState => {
    return { ...prevState, value1: "novo valor" }
});
```

Desta forma, o value2 continua com o valor original

Comment: Muito Obrigado! Eu também percebi que minha função (setValue) estava dentro de um useCallback e eu não tinha passado o estado como dependecia desse callback, então logo ele não mudava :)

Answer (score 1):

Uma outra forma de fazer o código que bem colocou o Bins!

Assim também deve funcionar:

```
setValue(prevState => ({ ...prevState, value1: 'novo valor' }));
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).